# Display relevant events after using date navigation in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, function, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using FullCalendar, and I need that when clicking the previous and next buttons, if you click on 'week' view, it should display the events for that specific week.

Also, if you navigate forward or backward using the week navigation icons, it should show the events for the respective week. I´m using JS.

```
 function nextbutton() {
    console.log("test");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fc-next-button").click(nextbutton);
});

 function prevbutton() {
    console.log("test");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fc-prev-button").click(prevbutton);
});
```

This is my code, I don't know what comes next. If someone can explain it, it will be very helpful to me

i would like an explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do not need to specifically handle click events on the next/prev buttons.

Instead you can set up an event source which can fetch data on-demand - see the [event sources documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source) for the possible options for configuring that.

That way, whenever you click on prev/next (or change the date range by any other means, such as changing the view type, [clicking a date navigation link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-nav-links) or using the [goToDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate) function), fullCalendar will *automatically* trigger a request to the configured event source(s) and provide it the start and end dates of the date range the calendar is about to display. The source can then use that date range information to filter its data store and return only events which occur within that range.

Here is a very simple demonstration using a custom callback function as an event source:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    nowIndicator: true,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
    },
    initialView: "timeGridWeek",
    events: fetchEvents
  });

  calendar.render();
});


//date data just for demo purposes
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

//static list of events for demo purposes. In a real scenario  you'd be more likely to make an AJAX request to a server-side API which then gets event data from a database, or something like that.
var events = [{
    title: "Sales Meeting",
    start: new Date(y, m, d - 1, 10, 30),
    end: new Date(y, m, d - 1, 11, 30),
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    title: "Marketing Meeting",
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
    end: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 30),
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    title: "Production Meeting",
    start: new Date(y, m, d + 2, 15, 30),
    end: new Date(y, m, d + 2, 16, 30),
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    title: "Management Meeting",
    start: new Date(y, m, d + 10, 14, 30),
    end: new Date(y, m, d + 10, 16, 30),
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    title: "Board Meeting",
    start: new Date(y, m, d - 10, 08, 30),
    end: new Date(y, m, d - 10, 16, 30),
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    title: "Annnual Conference",
    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
    end: new Date(y, m, d + 1),
    allDay: true
  }
]

//callback which conforms to the specification at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function
function fetchEvents(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {

  var filteredEvents = events.filter((event) => {
    let maxStart = new Date(Math.max(info.start, event.start));
    let minEnd = new Date(Math.min(info.end, event.end));
    return (maxStart < minEnd);
  });

  console.log(filteredEvents);
  successCallback(filteredEvents);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar/index.global.min.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Beyond correctly configuring the event source, you should not need to do anything else.